# Filter and sort in publish, subscribe, and data in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I am listing all notifications belonging to an user with

```
this.route('notifications', {
  path: '/notifications',
  template: 'notificationList',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('notifications');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Notifications.find(
      {userId: Meteor.userId()},
      {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
    );
  },
  fastRender: true
});
```

I am publishing the docs with

```
Meteor.publish("notifications", function () {
    return Notifications.find(
        {userId: this.userId},
        {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
    );
});
```

I am confused about what to do where. Do I have to filter for user id in both `Meteor.publish()` AND `data: ...`? Do I have to sort in both functions? I have seen that it is also possible to sort and filter in `Meteor.subscribe()`.

It seems a bit redundant to do almost the same in all three functions. Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling Meteor.publish it's usually necessary to sort so that the correct documents are sent when there's a limit being applied. For example, if you're only asking for 10 items then you'll need to sort them first to ensure that you have the *right* 10 items rather than 10 random results.

The client's sort order doesn't have any relation to that of the server's publish request, and there's no guarantee that they'll be the same. Consider for example the case where there are *multiple* publish requests posting to the *same* collection on the client, each with a different sort order. It would be impossible to have these results pre-sorted in a useful way.

Therefore, you usually also need to request that the items be sorted when accessing the collection on the client. The sort doesn't have to be the same as that on the server (although it often is).

As for Meteor.subscribe, the parameters you pass there depend on your publish function's parameters, so you can have your client pass the sort order to the publish function. This is useful when you need to have the same publish function return different results based on the sort order. Furthermore if the code for subscribing and supplying the data context are in the same route controller then you can have a single variable hold the sort condition and therefore reduce code duplication and potential for error.

Comment: Thank you :-) So `Meteor.subscribe('notifications', {sort: {createdAt: -1}})` doesn't make any sense? ... I don't use any parameters in my publish function on the server.

Comment: Correct. However you could always add a sort parameter to your publish function.

Comment: Thank you. I am subscribing notifications in my `waitOn` in `Router.configure` because I am showing the notifications in the navbar, but I am also subscribing these in a `waitOn` in `this.route('notifications', ...)`. Will these conflict or can they subscribe correctly "parallelly"?

Comment: That would result in two separate publications on the server that send their results to the same collection on the client. The results are merged (so there aren't any duplicates). That's fine, but you need to be aware that the collection contains results from both sources when displaying the information.

Comment: But am I really interested in waiting on the notifications to be loaded before the page is loaded? The notifications in the navbar is not that important for the page, so is it really necessary?

Comment: and thank you again! I'm learning much about Meteor today :-)

Comment: You don't have to wait for the subscription. You should post a separate question for this.